# curl .pbix file import POST error - HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length

Tags: shell, jenkins, curl

curl command gives a 411 error when running it in jenkins, works fine loally.

`curl -X POST "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{workspace_id}/imports?datasetDisplayName=Simple" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}" -F "data=@Sample.pbix"`

Comment: This issue is resolved, the problem was on the accessToken had extra whitespaces, but the error message was not meaningful here.